# Can I know the urls of insecure contents when IE prompt me “Only secure content is displayed”?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, https

When there is mixed http/https content in the webpage. IE prompt me this message.

I know how to disable this message.By the way, can I somehow know what exactly the insecure contents are (the urls)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Developer Tools (Settings menu > F12 Developer Tools) within Internet Explorer to view the resources being loaded using the Network tab, and look for any plain HTTP URLs as per the screenshot below.

[image: Dev Tools]

Answer (score 0):

Insecure content is content loaded over http (and not https).

It could be images, css, ...

The fix is to point to the secure (https) version of these contents.

Comment: .I understand.However I would like to know if I can determine the exactly image's url so that I can pinpoint which image is not using https.